# Python 3.2.2 custom object comparation fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

I have a python class declared like the following within a module

```
class Position:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = int(x)
    self.y = int(y)
def __str__(self):
    return self.toString()
def toString(self): #deprecated
    return "{x:"+str(self.x)+" y:"+str(self.y)+"}"
```

Now, later in the main program, I do a comparation like this:

```
can_pos = somestreet.endOfStreet(curPos).getPos() #returns a Position object
if(can_pos == atPos): # this returns False
  #blafoo
#if(can_pos.x == atPos.x and can_pos.y == atPos.y): #this returns True (and is expected)
```

I do not understand what the reason for the different behaviour could be ...

It would be very nice if someone could give me a hint on that :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you write comparison methods?  `__eq__`?  `__ne__`? etc.  If you didn't write any comparison methods, how do you think comparison should work?

Comment: thanks, fixed it. coming from cpp ;)

Comment: @S.Lott no I didn't write them, I thought python would compare all attributes by default

Comment: "I thought python would compare all attributes by default"?  Where have you seen this?  What tutorial are you using?  Did you read something that gave you this impression?  Can you provide a link or a reference?

Comment: @S.Lott I think your comment about x=int() is confusing. His example is self.x=int(x) and that's fine, why not? Also self.x = int() sets self.x to 0, that probably not useful but that's not what he's doing and it's also not nothing.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: earlier there were extraneous commands at class level before `__init__`.

Comment: @S.Lott I thought about CPP, but missed that they do pointer address comparation also (like (obj is obj2)). I wasn't following any tutorial. So much of what I think works exactly like same in python, so was my approach on this, but it was obviously wrong.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: comparing timestamps on the question and the "fixed it" comment, looks like it came in under the five-minute grace period (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to define at least `__eq__` and `__ne__` explicitly:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other
```

which gives

```
>>> a = Position(1,2)
>>> b = Position(1,2)
>>> c = Position(2,3)
>>> a == b
True
>>> a == c
False
>>> b == c
False
>>> a != a
False
>>> a != b
False
>>> a != c
True
```

Note, however, than in Python 2, you'll have:

```
>>> a > c
True
```

and other possibly undesirable behaviours, whereas in Python 3 (which you're using) you'll get

```
TypeError: unorderable types: Position() > Position()
```